# XAMPP MySQL start server failed

Tags: mysql, xampp

Error from XAMPP

```
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:37:06 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: We prefer that you ask an actual question.  And write some other sentences; e.g., describing what you’re doing and what’s happening.